# Job parameters in IBM datastage job

Tags: parameters, jobs, datastage

**IBM datastage** is a new tool for me and I'm unable to find any good pictorial and step by step tutorials for it. 
I'm having trouble in using **Job Parameters** in **Datastage**.

Anyone please help me how can we use **IBM Datastage job parameters** and **parameters sets**.

Answer (score 2):

It is very useful and flexible to use job parameters when designing Datastage jobs. Datastage 8 implements also job parameters sets which let users group the DataStage and QualityStage job parameters and store default values in files.

- Job parameters are defined in job properties windows
- Parameters can be used in directory and file names, to specify property values and in constraints and derivations
- Parameters are defined at runtime
- Surround parameters with the pound sign (#) to use parameters as file names and properties
- Job parameters can reference system environment variables

Have a look at the following [Tutorial1](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/infosphere/datastage-tip-using-job-parameters-without-losing-your-mind-8587) as well as [Tutorial2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21648569)

To expand on this, you can add an environment variable such as `$TargetDir` and as the default value assign `$PROJDEF`.  This `$PROJDEF` value is set at the Project level using Administrator.  The bonus of doing this is as you move through development environments and into production you do not have to redefine your Target Directory each time.  I hope this has opened your mind to the possibilities that exist!

Answer (score 0):

Also research Parameter Sets, which are collections of parameters that can be stored independently of jobs and re-used over and over.  By using "values files" you can set up different sets of default values for the parameters in Parameter Sets appropriate to different scenarios.